# convert decimal number to hex is printed in reverse order?

Tags: c, recursion, hex

I am writing a program to convert any decimal number to hex but the result I get is always in the reverse order. I am confused as to how to fix this?

```
/*simple implementation of decimal to hexdecimal
  algorithm is as follows:
  1. take the number and do floor division of 16
  2. write down the remainder
  3. repeat step 1 and 2 with the number from obtained from integer division
  4. when the resulting number is 0, the function returns
*/

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void printHex(int i){
    if(i == 0){
        return;
    }

    int rem = i % 16;
    switch(rem) {
        case 10: cout << "A"; break;
        case 11: cout << "B"; break;
        case 12: cout << "C"; break;
        case 13: cout << "D"; break;
        case 14: cout << "E"; break;
        case 15: cout << "F"; break;
        default: cout << rem; break;
    }

    printHex(i/16);
}

int main(){
    printHex(666);

    return 0;
}
```

666 outputs *A92* and not *29A*???

Thank you for the help.

Comment: C is not C++ .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your program prints before the recursive call. To fix, simply move the `printHex(i/16)` after the if statement.

```
void printHex(int i){
    if(i == 0){
        return;
    }
    printHex(i/16);

    int rem = i % 16;
    switch(rem) {
        case 10: cout << "A"; break;
        case 11: cout << "B"; break;
        case 12: cout << "C"; break;
        case 13: cout << "D"; break;
        case 14: cout << "E"; break;
        case 15: cout << "F"; break;
        default: cout << rem; break;
    }

}
```

Comment: oh i see. i am still lacking in recrusion

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the switch block, you can just write:

```
std::cout << "0123456789ABCDEF"[i % 16];
```

When you call `printHex(0)`, the output should be "0". Currently it is nothing.

Instead of `int`, use `unsigned int`, otherwise the output will be weird for large numbers.